# IndentationError: unexpected indent error while running the following program on visual studio code

Tags: python

```
 print("Hi")
 name = input("What's your name?")

 print("It's nice to meet you," name)
 answer = input("Are you enjoying the course?")
 
 if answer =="Yes":
      print("That's good to hear!")
 else:
      print("Oh no! That makes me sad!")
```

Comment: Usually you should be pointed to the line which caused the error.

Comment: I'm sure that vs code displays the error's line.

Comment: The only thing this produces is a syntax error on the second print, even if you fix that it runs [fine](https://ideone.com/4EHYt6)

Comment: @Sayse *every* line has a single leading space. Thus there is an "unexpected indent" on the *first* line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is, at least how you've formatted this code here, there is a space before every line. In Python, this is seen as an identation; and the first line, `print("Hi")`, is therefore indented when it is not supposed to be, causing an IndentationError.

The second is this line:

```
print("It's nice to meet you," name)
```

You've forgotten a comma between `"` and `name`. Instead, try something like this:

```
print("It's nice to meet you,", name)
```

or,

```
print("It's nice to meet you, {}".format(name))
```

Comment: I am learning python from beginner level...I wrote this source code on notepad, saved the code with .py extension and then imported the source code on Visual code Studio.

Comment: Now I have removed spaces and added comma as you said but still it is throwing an error.

Comment: @balisandeep89 Which error is it throwing? Does it show the line number of the error?

Comment: After making those changes, the code worked fine for me.